# How to authenticate channel users while using Unification Engine

Tags: unificationengine

UE allows us to write a single application to talk to multiple channels like Skype, fb, twitter, mail or even custom channels. However, does it provide a way to authenticate users before it allows the user of a channel to send messages through UE?

For example, say my UE app has an active Skype Connector. Will my app receive messages from any user or is there a way to filter message receiving from only known / authenticated users?

Answer (score 0):

There is no authentication, connector will receive all messages that comes to the Skype webhook.